# How can i store the text from a html input field in a node.js variable?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

My node.js code looks like this:

```
var connect = require('connect'); 
var serveStatic = require('serve-static'); 

connect().use(serveStatic("WebDir")).listen(80, function(){ 
    console.log('Server running on port 80...'); 
});
```

I would like to use an API and use the data from the input field in node.js
How can i exactly do it. The Input field is just a normal input field in HTML

Comment: Please show where you are trying to store.

Comment: like var username = textfield.innerHTML or something like that

Comment: in jQuery you can do it by using `var inp = $("#example").val();`, let me lookup for JS.

Comment: `var test = document.getElementById('getInput').value;` this is for JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a simple test setup for this using Node.js Express..

2 files: index.js, index.html

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">

        var sendInput = function() {
            var inputField = $('#inputField').val();

            console.log(inputField);

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:  'http://localhost:3000/inputData',
                crossDomain: true,
                data: JSON.stringify({ inputField: inputField }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(result, status){
                    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = result.nodeVariable;
                },
                error: function (errorMessage) {
                    console.error('Error: ', errorMessage);
                }
            });
        }

      </script>
</head>
<body topmargin="40" leftmargin="40">
 <div id="result">Loading..</div>
 </br>
 <button onClick="sendInput()">Send input to Node.js</button> : <input type="text" id="inputField" value="test value"><br>
 <div>
 <br/>Result: <p id="output"></p>
 <div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Server side, this is the node.js script.

**index.js**

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');
const port = (process.env.PORT || 3000);

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/inputData', (req, res, next) => {

    console.log('/inputData post: ', JSON.stringify(req.body));
    // Read the variable..
    var inputField = req.body.inputField;
    console.log('Input field: ', inputField);

    res.status(201).send(JSON.stringify({status: 'OK',  nodeVariable: inputField + " - updated by node."}))
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('Express listening on port ' + port);
```

Go to http://localhost:3000 on your browser to test.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. I will test if it works when I am home. Thank you already

Comment: And how can i change the value of the html tag in node?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show modifying HTML from a Node variable.